# How to disable a form field dependent on another input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to disable some form fields as long as other form fields are not filled yet.

https://jsfiddle.net/fk8wLvbp/

```
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
 <form class="form-inline">
  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputName2">Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" placeholder="Jane Doe">

  <label class="sr-only" for="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2">Username</label>
  <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <div class="input-group-text">@</div>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" placeholder="Username">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

In this example, I'd like to disable the `inlineFormInputGroupUsername2` field always if `inlineFormInputName2` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all you need the logic to be able to store the values ​​of the form

`main.js`

```js
let form = {name: '', username: ''}


const onChange = (evt) => {
   form = {...form, [evt.target.name]: evt.target.value}
}
```

`html`

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" id="inlineFormInputName2" name="name" onChange={onChange} placeholder="Jane Doe">

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inlineFormInputGroupUsername2" name="username" onChange={onChange}  disabled={form.name.length > 1} placeholder="Username">
```

with the disabled attribute we can do this.

Keep in mind that this is a simple example, you should split it into html and js files